# Manage query results in grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm working on a dashboard using Grafana and Influxdb as a database.

When I apply a query, this returns me 1 million of results and this is much information to load.

could I split this information into different datasets?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should to use [time aggregation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill), so it will return suitable amount of datapoints for graphing. Used aggregation function (MEAN,MAX,MIN,...) depends on your use case. Also suitable amounts depends on the use case. It is impossible to graph 1M datapoints on the graph which have 1000 pixels - 1k datapoints will be better, but graph will be still too fine; even if you need bar graph then you need even less datapoints.

Fortunately, Grafana offers `$__interval` macro, which is good starting point for the majority of graph cases and it creates proper time aggregation based on selected dashboard time range:

[image]